# Listing a certain part of filenames and their contents

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, find, filenames

I have a Linux machine with BusyBox,
which has a directory called `/data/var/lib/connman`. 
That directory holds some directories that I'm not interested in. 
But it contains many .config files that have a file name pattern
like "`wifi_<HASH1>_<HASH2>_managed_psk.config`". 
The file name in my example contains the interesting hash part,
`<HASH1>_<HASH2>`, which are alphanumeric characters. 
Examples of the full file names are:

- "wifi_ff001122334_567890123456_managed_psk.config"
- "wifi_778899ad_112233445566_managed_none.config"

Then each file is a text file and if it contains a line I'm interested in:

```
Name = <SSID>
```

The interesting part is `<SSID>`.

Real examples of that line are:

```
Name = MySSID
Name = r23$f"§F §"fsdfSdf
```

Now I want to get all the hashes from the file names
together with their value of *<SSID>*, like this:

```
<HASH> : <SSID>
```

That's my desired output:

```
MySSID : 01abcd89
MyOtherSSID : ff001122334455,
r23öf"§F§"fsdfSdf : 7876543ad
```

So we need to grab the hash part from the file name and at the same time look at the file's content that comes after "Name =".

I've played around with a combination of grep and awk but never got the desired output.

What command can I use to achieve that?

Comment: 1) You wrote *" like this: <HASH> : <SSID>..."* . Your sample output looks more like `<SSID> : <HASH>` . 2) are the *Real Examples* of `<SSID>` sample data from two different files, or both in one file? 3) if you're not going to use the `<HASH2>` from the file name, you can simplify your problem description by removing that info. (replace in filehame with `_otherstuff`?)` 4) The `awk` programing language is one tool that you can consider using. See [Awk Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and note the `FILENAME` variable as well as `$1, $2, $3, .... $NF` etc. ...

Comment: Update your question with your best attempt to solve the problem and readers will help you improve your understanding. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'for dir(test => / \.config $/ ) -> $fh {
                put join " : ",
                    $_.split(/ \s* \= \s* /)[1],
                    $fh.match(/ <?after wifi_ > .*? <?before _managed > /)
                for $fh.lines.grep(/^Name/)
             };'
```

This solution uses Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The code above relies on Raku's `dir()` and `grep()` routines, and therefore may be useful on platforms where classic shell-mediated file-globbing is absent/restricted (see SO discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400187/7270649)).

Briefly, raku is called with the -e option, which tells Raku's compiler (Rakudo) to compile and execute the given one-liner program. The `dir()` method is called with the `for` keyword which tells Raku to loop through the filename values obtained using the filter `test => / \.config $/`. Individual resultant filenames are assigned to the temporary variable `$fh` and iterated through inside the block.

- Once inside the block (reading from right-to-left), `$fh.lines.grep(/^Name/)` each filehandle is analyzed linewise for the presence of lines starting with the text "Name". If found Raku automatically assigns that line to `$_` the topic variable, which is then split on whitespace/equal-sign, and the `.[1]` second-element (SSID value) is isolated.
- The `$fh` filename is also massaged into final format, isolating `.*?` zero-or-more characters `<?after wifi_ >` after the text "wifi_" and `<?before _managed >` before the text "_managed".
- The resultant out`put` is `join`ed on the requested `:` whitespace/colon, with first the filename-fragment followed by the SSID-value.

Sample Input (pwd):

```
~$ ls *.config
wifi_778899ad_112233445566_managed_none.config      wifi_ff001122334_567890123456_managed_psk.config

~$ cat wifi_778899ad_112233445566_managed_none.config
Name : SSIDabcd
junk
Name : SSIDefgh

~$ cat wifi_ff001122334_567890123456_managed_psk.config
Name : SSID1234
junk
Name : SSID5678
```

Sample Output:

```
SSIDabcd : 778899ad_112233445566
SSIDefgh : 778899ad_112233445566
SSID1234 : ff001122334_567890123456
SSID5678 : ff001122334_567890123456
```

Note, isolating the filename-text fragment above with `match` relies on Raku's new idiom for lookaheads/lookbehinds. If you'd rather use Raku's `<(`…`)>` "capture-markers", that `match` operation can be instead written:

`$fh.match(/ wifi_  <( .*? )>  _managed /)`

https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir
https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://raku.org